# Are machines patched against WannaCry protected against the ongoing Petya attacks?

Tags: ransomware

Our environment has a few Windows 2012 R2 servers which is already patched against the WannaCry ransomware. The update installed was KB4012213.

- Is this good enough to protect against the ongoing Petya attacks?
- Anything else we should be doing other than disabling SMB service if
  unused?
- Does it spread itself through networked computers without user intervention?

Answer (score 9):

Making sure that SMBv1 is disabled is a good start to protecting against the Ethernalblue exploit.

**The malware also uses the WMIC and PSEXEC tools to infect machines that are fully-patched Windows computers.** Disabling WMIC is advised see here on how to disable WMIC: [https://msdn.microsoft.com/enus/library/aa826517(v=vs.85).aspx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa826517(v=vs.85).aspx)

I have also seen people saying to block remote use of local accounts via GPO but I have not seen too much on that yet.

There are also reports saying that paying the ransom will not reward you with the decryption key as the email that is used has since been blocked.

There have also just been some reports that if you power off the machine right as the message appears than it will not encrypt the files.
https://twitter.com/hackerfantastic/status/879775570766245888

UPDATE: There seems to now be a kill switch found to stop the attack all you have to do is create a folder C:\Windows\perfc

https://twitter.com/TheHackersNews/status/879782531146461185

Comment: This is a new account for me so I can only post so many links at one time but here are a few more links I thought would be useful:                                      Kaspersky Report: https://blog.kaspersky.com/new-ransomware-epidemics/17314/                                                                                              Link that shows the email is no longer active: https://twitter.com/TheHackersNews/status/879764529415995396

Comment: There's also some useful additional information on this now in this post from Microsoft https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/mmpc/2017/06/27/new-ransomware-old-techniques-petya-adds-worm-capabilities/

Comment: perfc is the filename without extension, not a folder.

Answer (score 2):

To protect yourself from Petya virus:

**Create a file perfc.dll**

At the time of attack, Petya looks for file C:\Windows\perfc.dll. If such a file on the computer already exists, then virus finishes work without infection.

To create such a file to protect against Petya, you can use the usual "Notepad". Experts also advise making the file read-only so that the virus can not make any changes to it.

**Install security patches**

The virus also spreads through the vulnerabilities of Windows CVE-2017-0199 and CVE-2017-0144. It is recommended to install security patches that close them:

https://portal.msrc.microsoft.com/en-US/security-guidance/advisory/CVE-2017-0199 https://portal.msrc.microsoft.com/en-US/security-guidance/advisory/CVE-2017-0144

We need to install security patches not only for Windows, but also for Microsoft Office.

It is also necessary to install patches that cover the previously exploited vulnerability for WannaCry:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/security/ms17-010.aspx

**Update antivirus signatures**

Antivirus software signatures database should be updated from June 27, 2017 not earlier than 20:00.

**Block resources**

The virus uses the following addresses, you should block access to them:

```
— 84.200.16[.]242
— 84.200.16[.]242/myguy.xls 
— french-cooking[.]com/myguy.exe
— 111.90.139[.]247
— COFFEINOFFICE[.]XYZ
```

Important! The dots are set for security reason. Do not click on the links. These addresses are published to block them manually.

**Disable TCP ports**

If the network already has infected workstations or servers, you must disable TCP ports 1024-1035, 139 and 445.

**Disable SMB protocol**

If you can not install security updates, disable the SMB v1 / v2 / v3 protocol on workstations and servers.

Read more: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2696547/how-to-enable-and-disable-smbv1-smbv2-and-smbv3-in-windows-and-windows

**Configure attack blocking**

In the case of NGFW / NGTP / IPS security features, configure blocking of attacks exploiting EternalBlue (MS17-010).

Comment: port 139 and not 135 (port 135 being the name exchange it doesn't accept payloads out of strict format). Any source for perfc.dll ? None of the security advice recomend to create a file with extension but a `perfc` file with no extension (didn't found a detailled explanation of this kill-switch yet).

Comment: @Tensibai It is recommended that a kill switch with an extension .dll (perhaps this is due to one of the versions of Petya virus).

Comment: @Tensibai Information on port 139 corrected

Comment: Would you mind sharing the source for the perfc.dll recommendation ? For example [IBM X-Force Advisory](https://exchange.xforce.ibmcloud.com/collection/Petya-Ransomware-Campaign-9c4316058c7a4c50931d135e62d55d89) just recommend a no extension file `c:\windows\perfc`

Comment: Article information security company InfoSec (written in russian) https://habrahabr.ru/company/infosecurity/blog/331788/

Comment: From [this gist](https://gist.github.com/katjahahn/3ec9bc1a3f5659bf98b457ea7a2fcf3a) where [this script is linked](https://pastebin.com/BxZ8CEzc) the main idea is to prevent the malware to create itself, as such creating `perfc`, `perfc.dat` and `perfc.dll` (just to add my latest informations)

Comment: @Tensibai Yes, it will be more reliable to create files both without an extension, and with an extension (.dll, .dat)

Comment: @Tensibai But this in any case isn't most reliable solution. Developers of Petya virus can change their code at any time.

Comment: From my [latest informations](https://securingtomorrow.mcafee.com/mcafee-labs/new-variant-petya-ransomware-spreading-like-wildfire/) (from mcafee), the kill switch can't be confirmed.

Comment: @Tensibai Yes, I think the virus has several versions and in later versions the kill switch has been disabled.